# How to properly join a process when KeyboardInterrupt received?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a server which I want to run in a separate process and handle `KeyBoardInterrupt` exception for stopping it:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

def server_spawner():
  server = HTTPServer(('', 12345), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
  try:
    server.serve_forever()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.shutdown()
    server.server_close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  server_proc = mp.Process(target=server_spawner)
  server_proc.start()
  server_proc.join()
```

but when I press `CTRL+C` I get such Traceback:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_miner.py", line 60, in <module>
    server_proc.join()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 145, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 154, in wait
    return self.poll(0)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 135, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

How to properly handle `KeyBoardInterrupt` and join a process in multiprocess program?

Comment: Catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` in your main process, then send a shutdown signal to the process.

Comment: @Will " then send a shutdown signal to the process" -- how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From [Jesse Noller](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/01/08/multiprocessingpool-and-keyboardinterrupt)'s blog.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

def server_spawner():
    server = HTTPServer(('', 12345), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.shutdown()
        server.server_close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_proc = mp.Process(target=server_spawner)
    server_proc.start()
    try:
        server_proc.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server_proc.terminate()
        server_proc.join()
```